# Problems to connect to RabbitMq docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to use MQTT Lens plugin as a client to a container running RabbitMQ on a virtual machine. To start the container on the virtual machine i run this command:

```
docker container run -d --hostname my-rabbit -p 8080:15672 -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 1883:1883 --name rabbitedgex rabbitmq:3
```

Then in my host machine, a configure a queue through the plugin administrator by going to the browser and typing:

```
10.0.2.6:8080
```

Finally, I used the MQTT Lens to try to send messages to the configure queue but it does not connect to the container.

To configure it I used this direction:

***tcp://10.0.2.6:1883***

`10.0.2.6` is the private address of the virtual machine where the container is running and 1883 is the usual port it uses to listen to clients and which I expose in the configuration of the container. Does any know which is the problem I am having, the why lens is not able to connect to the broker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried port 5672 - tcp://10.0.2.6:5672?

Comment: Yes, i tried that port and i did not work, i accept any other suggestion

Comment: This is what a i get when i ran the docker container ls command:                                                                                                  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                    NAMES
f6c0b7b8c68e        rabbitmq:3          "docker-entrypoint..."   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:1883->1883/tcp, 4369/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5671-5672->5671-5672/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->15672/tcp   rabbitedgex

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already enabled the '[rabbitmq_mqtt](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html)' plugin in the RAbbitMQ. In addition to that, you have to configure the default username and password of MQTT in the RabbitMQ.

rabbitmq.conf

```
mqtt.default_user= username
mqtt.default_pass= password
mqtt.allow_anonymous= false
mqtt.exchange= exchange_name
mqtt.vhost= /
```